# page sends file to curl i want to get download link insted

Tags: php, post, curl, download

there is a page that i need to post a password to it and then i get a file to download.
the post goes to the same page address its loads again and pop up the download manager (download starts automatically).
now i want to do the same but in curl, i posted the data to the url and then its sends me the file back but i don't want my script to download the whole file i want only to get a link to download it by myself.
how can i do that?

Comment: Hi Korrupt (: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What you're looking for is RegEx (Regular expressions), you should edit your post to add that tag etc

Comment: there is no download link in the page that i can grab by regex, download starts automatically.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. Hm I'm not sure. This has become a good question. You should edit your post to mention the downloading starting automatically, to clear up any confusion with others

Comment: i think i am on the way, i tried to do RANGE with curl and try to locate the meta tag that fire the download or so. but it not working maybe its a header that fire the download don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Maybe after login you're redirected via header to download page, which stats automatically? do yo have set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION on your curl session? You can try monitoring headers as described here: http://it.toolbox.com/wiki/index.php/Use_curl_from_PHP_-_processing_response_headers

Comment: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION was set to TRUE i will change it to FALSE, maybe now i will get the page that redirects me, i will try to find the filename in the headers and grab it.

Comment: when you set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to FALSE - curl will stop and probably will return no content, so you need to find the way to grab headers and look download link (e.g. "Location: ..." header, if it is done via location header of course)

Comment: ok, thanks you. i will update here if that will solve it.

Comment: Check out web-sniffer.com to pick apart your HTTP request. It should help you determine how the page works on the protocol level.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you most probably can't. Such password protected download system usually checks either cookies or browser / environment based variables. Getting the link itself shouldn't be problem, however you could not use it outside this generator's scope anyway.

Comment: i got the headers without the body, there i see only the content size, no file name or link, if the content size is like the file size then i assume the password is right. now i dont want to give the person the password only the link, so how can i do that i dont want my curl server to download all the file and send it to the person.
maybe i will send a hidden form with the correct password to the person and then it will automatically post it to the right server and get the file, but there is a chance that the user can see the password if he have firebug. there is another way you recommend?

Comment: here is what i get (with a curl limit of 3 sec if it was without limit it will download the all file):
http://pagesalike.com/picspile/images/2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

firstly you need to post that password with curl assuming "on specific form. the form will take you to the downloading page" now you need to use regex (regular expressions).
filter the data you want then save it on other variable to re-use it.

Comment: but the received data is the whole file i don't want to download it with curl, i want to grab only the link to it and send it to the user to download.

Answer (score 0):

There is for sure a redirection after you hit 1st page with POST. Look for that redirection with curl and read http response headers: Content-Location or Location or even Refresh

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the automatic download you have to set the curl opt to not follow redirects. I can't remember the exact command but curl by default will follow auto refreshes and URL redirects, which happen in split seconds so humans don't actually see it happening.

I kinda don't understand what you really want to do, but if you just want a link then have the php script perform the entire curl post and everything when they click it. Doesn't matter what the web server will require a password before access to a file, you can't skip that step.